# The local variable inlines may not have been initialized

Tags: java, массивы

Как исправить ошибку?

Есть код:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Startx {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int lines;
    String[] inlines; //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Startx.main(Startx.java:17)
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    lines = (int) br.read();

    for(int line = 1; line <= lines; line++) {
        System.out.println(line + "]    ");
        inlines[line] = br.readLine();
    }
    for(String inline  : inlines) System.out.println(inline);

    }
}
```

Который выдаёт ошибку в объявлении `inlines[]`. Причём выдаёт он её, находясь на строке:

```
inlines[line] = br.readLine(); //The local variable inlines may not have been initialized
```

Насколько я понимаю, надо как-то подругому объявить `inlines[]`. Но как?

Comment: Так нужно инициализировать массив: String[] inlines = new String[];

Comment: @Rams666 Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий код:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Startx {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int lines;
    String[] inlines; //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Startx.main(Startx.java:17)
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    lines = (int) br.read();
    inlines = new String[lines];

    for(int line = 1; line <= lines; line++) {
        System.out.println(line + "]    ");
        inlines[line] = br.readLine();
    }
    for(String inline  : inlines) System.out.println(inline);

    }
}
```